# How to check for empty cells in Gridbaglayout?

Tags: java, cells, gridbaglayout

How to check for empty cells in gridbaglayout? 
e.g. there are 100 cells, only 10 filled with label or pictures?

Comment: There's no standard API (that I can see) to get at all the constraints within a `GridBagLayout`. The question is: Why do you need to do this? If you added all the components to the layout, don't you already know where the are? Can you add some more detail to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Well the GridBagLayout has a getConstraints(Component) method. So you could get all the components in the Container and then get the constraint for each component. The constraint will contain the gridX/gridY value which you could use to populate a 2D array. You may also not to consider the gridWidth/gridHeight values.

So the answer is yes you could derive all the information.

Comment: +1 : You can derive the values, even though there isn't a direct provision for it in the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [table2gridbag](http://www.onyxbits.de/table2gridbag) to avoid producing empty cells in the first place. It's a console tool that takes an HTML table, describing the layout, and transforms it into suitable Java source code for configuring the `GridbBaglayoutManager` to produce an equivalent layout.